# Spring binding checkbox list without viewresolver

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, checkbox, underscore.js

I want to bind few of my checkboxes so that on submit I will have them in my list:

```
private List<String> checkboxList;
```

Since I'm not using view resolver i tried to make those like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList" value="4"/>
```

so that when any of them gets checked and submited I will have list of checked in my checkboxList. I have already simple text input binded to my form and that works fine so I guess the problem is with html description of such list.

My controller signature is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(UploadItem uploadItem, HttpSession session,
        Locale locale, Model model) throws Exception {
```

where uploadItem is:

```
 private String filename;
 private List<CommonsMultipartFile> fileData;
 private List<String> checkboxList;
```

filename and fileData works fine

```
public List<String> getCheckboxList() {
    return checkboxList;
}

public void setCheckboxList(List<String> checkboxList) {
    this.checkboxList = checkboxList;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI *view resolver* is a MVC component which is completely unrelated to parameter binding. Please share your controller code with us as well (at least the handler method signature).

Comment: i know it's unrelated but I couldn't find any exaples with clean html instead of jsp. Edited question with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like everything is working but my problem is that those checkboxes are generated from underscore.js template so I will have to find workaroud for that.